# How exactly do I get my "Dog" renamed to "Dogmeat"?

Tags: fallout-4

I'm level 19 or so and my Dog is still named "Dog" and not "Dogmeat" like I'm seeing around the internet.

Through a little research I've heard things like "Just keep doing stuff for the minutemen" or "Mama Murphy will tell you the name of your dog."

I think I've done everything for the minutemen. I have the castle and now I seem to be granted endless quests of helping random groups around the commonwealth.

Mama Murphy also doesn't seem to care about my dog at all. I've told my dog to investigate her, but nothing. I've given her Jet and built her chair. Now she's asking for Mentats. If I keep doing stuff for her will she eventually name my dog?

Or do I need to do something else entirely?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spoiler:

> During the quest "getting a clue," if you have Dogmeat with you you can refer to him for the purposes of being a bloodhound.

This will fix it.

Comment: It's not the only way, because I haven't done "getting a clue" and my dog is called Dogmeat. I don't know when he changed name, it didn't seem to be a result of any conversation I remember, I just noticed it had changed and thought "oh, when did his name change?!"

Comment: You do not need to have dog with you for this to happen. For me, dog was still referred to as dogmeat, and spawned outside of Nicks agency. **it is also worth noting that this particular method is known as a bug**. Characters can accidentally refer to dog as "dogmeat", regardless of if you had his name change through Mama Murphy. From that point on, dogs name changes to dogmeat.

Comment: Characters may refer to the dog as dogmeat even from the beginning. Immediately after I got Preston as companion (after his second mission) I asked him to come with me and he said "Don't worry Dogmeat, I'll take good care of him".